# C# how to refresh serial port in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox, serial-port

i want to make my application can refresh serial port in c#. when list of port(In ComboBox) is empty and i hit button `refresh`, it's work perfectly and show the list of active port. but if i disconnected the `Serial Port` and i hit `refresh` button, actually it's must make the list of port(In Combobox) is empty because the serial port is disconnected. So how to make when i hit `refresh` button and the condition is disconnected, we make all of port list(in Combobox ) is empty ?

this is my code in refresh button:

```
private void button2_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(cboPort.Text))
    {
        comm.SetPortNameValues(cboPort);

        for (int i = 0; i < cboPort.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string value = cboPort.GetItemText(cboPort.Items[i]);

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                string a = cboPort.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                cboPort.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
     }
     else if ((cboPort.Text) != " " && cboPort.SelectedIndex == -1)
     {
           cboPort.Text = " ";
           return;
     }
}
```

this is my code in setportnamevalues :

```
    public void SetPortNameValues(object obj)
    {
        foreach (string str in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
             ((ComboBox)obj).Items.Add(str);   
        }
    }
```

my expetation is :

`1. i connect serial port 
2. i run my app 
3. i disconnect serial port
4. i hit refresh
5. final result is port list empty in combobox`

thanks for helping and responses, i am still new in c#. Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Finally get the answer.

this is modification of setportnamevalues :

```
public void SetPortNameValues(object obj)
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames(); // load all name of com ports to string
        ((ComboBox)obj).Items.Clear(); //delete previous names in combobox items

        foreach (string port in ports) //add this names to comboboxPort items
        {
            ((ComboBox)obj).Items.Add(port); //if there are some com ports ,select first
        }
        if (((ComboBox)obj).Items.Count > 0)
        {
            ((ComboBox)obj).SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ((ComboBox)obj).Text = " "; //if there are no com ports ,write Empty
        }
    }
```

in here modification in button action :

```
    private void button2_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comm.SetPortNameValues(cboPort);
    }
```

yeah, finally i get what i want.

Answer (score 0):

My solution as below

1. Initialize COM list
2. Add serialPort_OnClick event for combobox so that whenever user click on combobox, the COM items will be reloaded

   ```
   private void InitializePortSetting()
   {
       mDateTime = DateTime.Now;
       //1. Setting port list

       // Get a list of serial port names.
       portList = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
       Console.WriteLine("The following serial ports were found:");
       // Display each port name to the console.
       foreach (string port in portList)
       {
           port_name.Items.Add(port);
       }
   }
   private void serialPort_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       port_name.Items.Clear();
       port_name.Text = "";
       //port_name.Dispose();
       // Get a list of serial port names.
       portList = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
       Console.WriteLine("The following serial ports were found:");
       // Display each port name to the console.
       foreach (string port in portList)
       {
           port_name.Items.Add(port);
       }
   }
   ```